# mod_wsgi on Apache and Windows 7

Tags: django, apache, server, mod-wsgi

I installed Apache and mod_wsgi on Win 7 and copied config text output of mod_wsgi into httpd.conf.

I also check and see server working before mod_wsgi.

Now when I try to connect on local host I get a connection refused. After some research I found out I should add mod_wsgi.server to my app settings. I did it and ran runmodwsgi which failed because it was running a script in Windows which used os.getuid. Not valid in Windows. Is it mandatory to add mod_wsgi to isntalled apps in django project? Not mentioned in [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html).

If so what can I do for os.getuid in Windows?

Beside these why I get connection refused and no log if only my handler config is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran httpd from cmd and found the error:

> [Fri Dec 21 10:11:17.538864 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 64084:tid 180]
>   mod_wsgi (pid=64084): Initializing Python. Fatal Python error:
>   Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Don't know the reason yet.

[UPDATE]
Changed PYTHONHOME to python base path and it is working now. There most be an in compatibility between venv and setuptools.

Comment: Uninstalled Python
Installed last version FOR ALL USERS
Updated pip
Installed needed modules
Created a new venv referencing base libs in the django site folder
Ran mod_wsgi-express module-config and pasted its output to Apache conf
Created a dedicated user accounts with required rights
In windows set the password for the Apache service in related msc snippet
Fixed