# Apache permission problem when loading mod_wsgi

Tags: windows, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf, privileges

I installed ApacheLounge 14 and configured it to use mod_wsgi. When I run in it as admin it works fine. When I run it as a dedicated user I created for Apache, httpd loads every module except mod_wsgi: "The specified module could not be found.". As was instructed in the guide I logged in as the apache_user and tried to access everything including logs, exes, django files and mode_wsgi. No problem. At the same session when I run httpd from cmd I again get the module not found error. When I run it as admin httpd runs with no problem.

I gave the apache_user act as system and full control of every folder it needed. Is it possible that Apache finds the module but have problem loading it and gives that error instead?

Answer (score 0):

Used SysInternals' procmon to see whats going on down there. Saw httpd was looking everywhere for Python.dll. So it meant the dll wasn't in the path. Actually the dll it was supposed to use was out of its access rights. So installed Python for all users an reconfigured everything to fix it. As explained i the [sister post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848365/mod-wsgi-on-apache-and-windows-7/53880372#53880372).